# Will an application written for one version of .net 4 run on later versions?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

If I compile an application targeting .net 4.6, will it run on .net 4.7? If not, will an application targeting .net 4.7, run on .net 4.7.1?

My question is not on these specific versions only. These are just examples. But I will restrict this to within CLR 4.

**EDIT**

Just testing is not enough. If something works in one case it might still not work in others.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/application-compatibility)

Comment: All of the .NET 4 series so far have been *in place updates*. That is, if you install 4.7.1, you no longer "have" 4.7 or 4.6 installed. You should be able to deduce the compatibility from just that (unless you expect people who use more than one piece of .NET based software to have a separate machine for each .NET version)

Comment: If it works in certain cases is not enough. I want to know whether they are _supposed_ to work. In any case - I have many .net versions on my computers because they are used for programming. Most client machines won't.

Comment: [Configuring Assembly Binding Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/configuring-assembly-binding-redirection)

Comment: @RufusL Your link is the answer. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. See my first comment here.

Comment: I don't have time to post a proper answer right now, so you or someone else can take it! :)

Comment: @RufusL Done. Thank you very much for the link! That's much better than just users telling me their opinion without any backing.

Comment: Well, it's not an opinion - applications either run or not - no middle ground.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev Not exactly. An application might run. Others might not. The link itself mentions that. Certain bug fixes and others can make an app incompatible with later versions. I assume most apps will run fine, but some won't. So testing wouldn't give us the full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'Rufus L' has commented - the answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/application-compatibility).

Most notably:

> Compatibility ensures that each version is additive, so previous
>   versions will still work.

but also mentions:

> ...changes to previous functionality ... can cause compatibility
>   problems...